# Capturing frame from webcam, it return only 1 frame in opencv cv2.VideoCapture()

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm new to image processing.

I'm trying to build traffic light detection following one of papers in Python OpenCV.

But I got an error I can't understand.

Here is the code.

```
# TL_Detection.py

import cv2
import numpy as np 


def Video():
    try:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/aicar/Downloads/tf_test.mp4')

    except:
        print('no cam error')
        return

    # cap.set(3, 480)
    # cap.set(4, 320)

    frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    size = (frameWidth, frameHeight)
    cap.set(3, frameWidth)
    cap.set(4, frameHeight)

    cnt = 0

    # while cap.isOpened():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # if not cap.isOpened():
        #     cap.open('/home/aicar/Downloads/tf_test.mp4')
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        print(ret, cnt)
        if not ret:
            print('no ret error')
            break


        cnt += 1
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
Video()
```

This code returns like the following.

```
True 0
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/aicar/opencv/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 339
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aicar/codes_juyeong/TL_detection.py", line 53, in <module>
    Video()
  File "/home/aicar/codes_juyeong/TL_detection.py", line 33, in Video
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: /home/aicar/opencv/opencv-3.4.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:339: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Why can't it get frame after getting only the first frame ?
The webcam is connected correctly.

need your help. Thanks.

Comment: cap.release() cv2.destroyAllWindows() should be outside while True: loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you release your cap too early, it's in the true loop. so get it out of this loop and you program will run without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

To capture frame after frame try this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
   cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# while cap.isOpened():
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if not cap.isOpened():
    #     cap.open('/home/aicar/Downloads/tf_test.mp4')
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    print(ret, cnt)
    if not ret:
        print('no ret error')
        break


    cnt += 1

# take it out of while loop
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```